# How to access IOmNavigator c++ interface

Tags: internet-explorer, webbrowser-control, mshtml

I have mshtml hosted in my c++ app.  I tried to query the IHTMLDocument for IOmNavigator but got back nothing.  I also tried to do the same with IHTMLWindow2 with no luck.

I am trying to access IOmNavigator to get browser version number.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You probably need to QueryService() something, but I'm not sure what or what SID to ask for.

Comment: Doing some digging on the interwebs it looks like people are claiming IHTMLWindow2 has a get_navigator() method.  This isn't listed on MSDN though, so I'm not sure if the docs are wrong or these people are on crack.

Comment: @i_am_jorf  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa741467.aspx And you can find the method in `<mshtml.h>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
IHTMLDocument2 *pDoc; IHTMLWindow2 *ihw; IOmNavigator *nvg; BSTR uastr; AnsiString mouni;
if (SUCCEEDED(CppWebBrowser1->Document->QueryInterface(IID_IHTMLDocument2,(void**)&pDoc)))
{
  pDoc->get_parentWindow(&ihw); ihw->get_navigator(&nvg); nvg->get_userAgent(&uastr);
  mouni=AnsiString(uastr).UpperCase(); nvg->Release(); ihw->Release(); pDoc->Release();
  if (mouni.Pos("TRIDENT")>0 && mouni.Pos("MSIE")==0) { lmrg=8; tmrg=8;}
}
```

Code snip above (BCB5) shows how to get IHTMLDocument2 interface, then the IHTMLWindow2 interface, then the IOmNavigator interface, then the useragent string, and set some margins accordingly (IE11 is different to IE10 and previous versions in the way it renders pages). HTH, Graphic.